# Java: JFileChooser getting international filenames

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser and getting file names with Chinese characters in them. JFileChooser displays them properly, and I want to be able to capture these file names and display them back to the user.

I have filename: 03 玩愛之徒.mp3

But I end up displaying: 03 ????.mp3

In my code I get...

```
File f1 = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
log("f1="+ f1.getName());                         // gets me 03 ????.mp3
byte[] fname1 = f1.getName().getBytes();          // gets me [B@3f72c47b  
byte[] fname2 = f1.getName().getBytes("UTF-16");  // gets me [B@411b1d80
```

I know I am close, but am needing a little help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in the file name, but in the fonts which are being used to read the logs. If you are directing the logs to a file, try reading it in a unicode compatible editor, Also make sure that log is using BufferedWriter or similar class (for writing to file/screen).

Comment: Ignore the log part - I am trying to save just the filename in the unicode format and display this back to the user. I am storing it in table format DefaultTableModel. BufferedWriter appears to be for files, I will continue looking for the solution to this...

Comment: DefaultTableModel is used by JTable, which uses fonts available with JRE, which often displays ? or boxes when rendering unicode strings. Try displaying your file name in a JLabel with a font which is capable of displaying Chinese font to make sure its not the issue of reading files using JFileChooser.

Comment: You are correct. The filenames with asian characters properly display in labels. I had the table using Calibri (windows font). I added a unicode font to the table ("Dialog") - "analysisTable.setFont(uniFont);" and it works like a charm. Thanks for the direction in tracking this down.