# Netbeans can't read utf8 file names in mac

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, utf-8, filenames

I have a project on my eclipse, one of its methods are reading list of files from a folder.
when I run it from eclipse or from an exported jar, its fine and works great.

But I have another project on my netbeans for the GUI of this app where I include the exported jar (which works fine) but when I run or export this project from netbeans, it just can't read non-english filenames, it's converting the filenames to something like this

```
???????? ???? ??? .mp3
```

I tried to add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the `netbeans.conf`
and I also tried to select the encoding in the netbeans project properties but no luck.

here is some code:

```
public SFile(String path, FileFilter filter) {
    File f = null;
    f = new File(path);
    directory = f.isDirectory();
    if (directory) {
        children = new ArrayList<SFile>();
        File[] ki = f.listFiles(filter); // here i see the ???? ????.mp3
        ArrayList<File> kids = new ArrayList<File>();
        Collections.addAll(kids, ki);
        Collections.sort(kids, comparator);
        for (File k : kids) {
            if (k.isDirectory() && k.listFiles(filter).length == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            children.add(new SFile(k.getAbsolutePath(), filter));
        }
    } else {
        // some more code...
    }
}
```

the filter code:

```
new FileFilter() { 
     public boolean accept(final File pathname) { 
     try {
         return pathname.getCanonicalPath().endsWith(".mp3") || pathname.isDirectory();
     } catch (final IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); 
     } 
     return false; 
     }
};
```

my project dependencies:

```
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/asm-3.1.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/grizzly-framework-2.2.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/grizzly-http-2.2.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/grizzly-http-server-2.2.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/grizzly-rcm-2.2.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/gson-2.2.2.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/javax.servlet-api-3.1-b05.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/jersey-bundle-1.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/jersey-core-1.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/jersey-grizzly2-1.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/jersey-server-1.16.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/jid3lib-0.5.4.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/cling-mediarenderer-2.0-alpha2-standalone.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/cling-workbench-2.0-alpha2-standalone.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/core/seamless-http-1.0-alpha2.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/core/seamless-util-1.0-alpha2.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/core/seamless-xml-1.0-alpha2.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/support/cling-support-2.0-alpha2.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/cling-distribution-2.0-alpha2/core/cling-core-2.0-alpha2.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/MpegAudioSPI1.9.5/mp3spi1.9.5.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/MpegAudioSPI1.9.5/lib/jl1.0.1.jar
/Users/dima/Dev/RSLib/MpegAudioSPI1.9.5/lib/tritonus_share.jar
```

Comment: Are you reading a list of filenames then displaying them in a GUI? If so, lets see the display code.

Comment: no, i am not displaying them, im indexing all the files to hashmap with incrementing ID, when i stop for debugging, i see the non english filenames as ???????.mp3 and the java cant read them

Comment: "i see the non english filenames as ???????.mp3" Where do you see them? In the IDE somewhere? On a watch? In the output pane?

Comment: it would also be useful to see the actual code that reads the filename

Comment: i see it when i debug, there is a String path (a good one,english) and i create a File f, and do a listFiles(), in there, when i am watching the returned array, the non-english ones are  "??????.mp3", i updated my question, added the code.

Comment: You should go to them and fill a bug report...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on java 7 `listFiles` is reported broken on mac OS X - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762173/file-listfiles-on-openjdk7-os-x-broken-on-file-names-that-contain-a-euro-symbo) and links there. If updating does not fix it you should consider [moving to nio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893205/how-to-replace-file-listfilesfilefilter-filter-with-nio-in-java-7) - or see [here](http://pastebin.com/wWkXBJpK).
I'd ike to see the filter you pass in `listFiles(filter);`

Comment: strange thing, when im using the nio like you said in a main method, it works(on the eclipse currently) but when im using it inside my code, its also returns "??? ????????.mp3", any ideas?

Comment: @DimaGoltsman : did you try with latest java 1.7 ? Also please be sure to post _all the code that modifies the pathname_ I suspect you (or your dependencies) are calling a String constructor with the default encoding

Comment: installed JDKu21 , still the same

Comment: i just noticed that in the JFileChooser itself, its also unknown symbols instead of the real filename...

Comment: @DimaGoltsman : Please remove `javax.servlet-api-3.1-b05.jar` - it leads to all kind of crazy behavior - may be the cause. Probably you should go ahead and delete other jars in your classpath - please read : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993522/281545. You did it for not setting a server up in netbeans ? Go ahead and set the server up !

Comment: i removed it, and also removed the asm, still the same... i think the problem is much deeper because its also showing wrong filenames in jfilechooser

Comment: OK!!!! my search is over, the problem was netbeans, when i changed to java 1.6 it was still compiling with 1.7, i removed the 1.6 platform from the properties in netbeans and added it again, and now it works! thank you for your time! so we can understand that java 1.7 still not fixed

Comment: @DimaGoltsman : Ah great - if you are to display those filenames have a look [here](http://shamsmi.blogspot.gr/2008/03/internationalize-swings-jfilechooser-in.html) - and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477610/java-jfilechooser-getting-international-filenames). Update your question with your updated dependencies. Always clean build your project to be sure. Glad to help and _thanks for the bounty_ :))